# SwiftUI: Rearrange items in Scrollable LazyVGrid with Draggable and DropDestination

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to rearrange or move items in a LazyVGrid inside a ScrollView using [.draggable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/draggable(_:preview:)?changes=_1) and [.dropDestination](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/shortcutslink/dropdestination(for:action:istargeted:)?changes=latest_major&language=o_8) view modifier based on the post [here](https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/first-experience-with-transferable-implementing-drag-and-drop-in-swiftui/).
My problem is that I need to know which item is being dragged and particularly when the user stops dragging the item, much like onEnded for DragGesture. This works fine when the item is dropped inside a view with a .dropDestination but if the user drops it outside the item get "stuck" as being the draggedItem. See the video:
[Drag and Drop outside of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFFsj.gif)
Is there a way to tell when the item is dropped, regardless of where it's dropped?

Here's my code currently which only works if item is dropped within the views with .dropDestination.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension UTType {
    static var itemTransferable = UTType(exportedAs: "com.styrka.DragableGrid.item")
}

struct ItemDraggable: Identifiable, Equatable, Transferable, Codable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(for: ItemDraggable.self, contentType: .itemTransferable)
    }
    var id: Int
}

struct MainView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(160)),
        GridItem(.fixed(160))
    ]
    @State private var items = (0..<20).map { ItemDraggable(id: $0) }
    @State private var draggingItem: ItemDraggable?
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Items, dragging: \(draggingItem?.id ?? -1)")
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    DraggableView(item: item, draggingItem: $draggingItem)
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .dropDestination(for: ItemDraggable.self) { items, location in
            // User to drop items outside but does not cover the whole app
            draggingItem = nil
            return true
        }
    }
}

struct DraggableView: View {
    var item: ItemDraggable
    @Binding var draggingItem: ItemDraggable?
    @State private var borderColor: Color = .black
    @State private var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(item.id)").font(.caption)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill(.blue).opacity(0.6))
            .border(borderColor, width: borderWidth)
            .opacity(item == draggingItem ? 0.1 : 1)
            .draggable(item, preview: {
                Text("Dragging item \(item.id)")
                    .onAppear {
                        // Set binding when draggable Preview appears..
                        draggingItem = item
                    }
                    .onDisappear{
                        // Called as soon as the dragged item leaves the 'DraggedView' frame
                        //draggingItem = nil
                    }}
            )
            .dropDestination(for: ItemDraggable.self) { items, location in
                draggingItem = nil
                return true
            } isTargeted: { inDropArea in
                borderColor = inDropArea ? .accentColor : .black
                borderWidth = inDropArea ? 10.0 : 0.0
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This has to either be a bug or a very confusing implementation of drag and drop. It feels a little odd to be hooking to the  appear/disappear of the draggable item for this to begin with but that seems to be the intended path but a non-functional one at that.

Comment: I did not, we are using lists onMove instead as of now...